# 'Rita is not hardworking like Samson.' In this sentence, is Samson hardworking?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

It could sound like Samson is hardworking because of the 'not',  but it can also sound like Samson isn't hardworking because of the 'like'. So is Samson hardworking or not? Thank you! :)

Comment: The quote implies that Samson is hardworking. Adding a comma before "*like Samson*" makes him as lazy as Rita.

Comment: @Lawrence is correct on both counts but it's worth pointing out that in both cases there is still a degree of ambiguity: in other words, it's hard to be certain what the writer intended.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I agree that there's still a measure of ambiguity in both cases.

Comment: The way to eliminate any ambiguity is to add “is” at the end. “Rita is not hard working like Samson is.”

Comment: Ambiguity could so easily have been avoided by writing:  “Rita, like (or ‘unlike, as applicable) Samson, is not hardworking.”  Then there is no possibility of misunderstanding.